# Nesting single quotes

Tags: objective-c, c, escaping, nested

There doesn't seem to be a question for this, and it seems strange that I don't know this.  When I program in c/objective-c, must I escape single quotes nested within double quotes.

example

`"'"` or `"''"`

is this needed

`"\'"` or `"\'\'"`

thanks

Comment: You do not need to escape single quotes inside double quotes in Objectice C or C. Out of curiosity, what languages do require escaping single quotes inside double quotes?

Comment: I am not sure of any languages that do, but I assumed it could occur

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, escaping is unnecessary for single-quotes.